# Hibernate JPA EntityManager possibly causing performance issues?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, entitymanager, hibernate-entitymanager

Main Problem: We are working on a back end application created from Java 8. As we add more and more DAO classes and methods in our back end, some queries have become slower. We already have eliminated the possibility that this could be due to the queries themselves or the database. The queries have no issues when run directly on a tool like SQL Developer. They execute quickly. The issue is when we run them in our application's back end, they run really slow. Query concurrency also seem to be not a cause since we don't execute queries asychronously.

So with this, now we think it could be due to our codes or configuration. We use JPA for our queries and its implemented via Spring and Hibernate. This we how we defined our EntityManager.

```
@Repository
public class MyDao {
  @PersistenceContext(unitName = "myPersistenceUnit")
  protected EntityManager entityManager;

  public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
     return entityManager;
  }

  //dao methods. We use the same EntityManager for every DAO method
}
```

### Questions

1. Is there anything wrong with our configuration?
2. Could the problem of having slow execution times be related to how we create our EntityManager?
3. Should we instantiate a new EntityManager every time?

One useful data we have found is that when we took a look at the database statistics, executing our queries showed very high I/O usage. Executing them on SQL developer do not produce the same I/O statistics.

Can anyone help us on this? our database by the way is Oracle 12c

Comment: *Should we instantiate a new EntityManager every time* definelty - if by "every time" you mean single unit of work.

Comment: So since "the same queries" yelds different "statistics" on the same rdbms instance the answer is clear - those are not the same queries. You either not dong the same queries or maybe you are victim of gazillion support queries like eg relation fetching. Turn SQL debug on to at least see what kind of (and how many of them) prepared statemets are executed.

Comment: @Antoniossss: for example, a single request involves multiple DAO calls. We currently use one EntityManager for all. For do we need to instantiate a new EntityManager for every DAO call?

Comment: It all depends how you define your unit of work. As a rule of thumb you could say that your unit of work can be as large as transaction - assuming you have short robust transactions.